Visualizing study population using ggplot
I am trying to visualize my study population by using ggplot but cannot really seem to make it look nice.
Attached is a photo of what it looks like right now, but I would ideally like to not have a scatter plot but for it to rather look like a stacked area chart or with lines connecting the circles (to show how those for eg. born in 1945 will be followed for the entire follow-up between ages 50-75). Is there any way to add highlights or connect the dots/create lines that anyone can think of? Thankful for any input!
# Plot 
ggplot(df_sample, aes(x = year, y = age, color = as.factor(fodelsear))) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +  # Add points on the lines
  labs(
    title = "Study Population",
    x = "Follow-up Year",
    y = "Age",
    color = "Birth Cohort"  
  ) +
 #scale_color_manual(values = custom_palette) +  # Apply custom color palette
  theme_minimal() +  # Apply clean theme
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),  # Center title
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),  # Angle x-axis labels
    legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),  # Center legend title
    legend.text = element_text(size = 10),  # Adjust legend text size if needed
    legend.position = "right"  # Position legend as needed
  )


I have tried to plot many different things, including a stacked area chart but I cannot make it run (the plot is empty). The image above is the closest I can get to.

+geom_line(aes(group = fodelsear))?

It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from dput() or reprex::reprex() and any libraries you are using. Check it out: making R reproducible questions. That being said, instead of geom_point(), you could use geom_point( stat = "align", position = "stack"). For the best answers, though, edit your question and make it reproducible.

It is helpful to consider which message should be conveyed in the first place (whether with a visual, a table, a paragraph ...). The present chart illustrates how every single year people grow one year older, regardless of age (cohort), which is trivial. Your might, e.g., want to show how the age distribution of the participants shifts from one year to another (boxplot, violin plot, population pyramids etc). Often, the choice of chart type and design follows from the message.

It sounds to me like you're looking for a Lexis-diagram. Have a look at https://github.com/ottlngr/LexisPlotR and see if that helps you,
